# How to explicitly reset current branch state while switching branches with go_router?

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-go-router

I use go_router's `StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack` to implement a design with bottomNavBar. How can I reset the current branch to its original state AND go to another branch at the same time?

Tab A is used to create or edit a single item. In A, I have some routes for a multi-step process to gather data for a new item. Eventually, the item is created and the user is sent to another tab C using `context.goNamed(AppRoute.tabC.name)`

The problem is that tab A's state is retained during the redirect. So if the user later switches back to that tab, they will see the last form of the data gathering process, not the first form ready to accept fresh inputs.

Question: How can I make sure tab A is reset to the initial route while jumping to a different tab?

Update: I've used a fork of the official [stateful_shell_route example](https://github.com/githubmonkey/flutter_packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart) in the go_router package to demonstrate what I want to accomplish.
https://github.com/githubmonkey/flutter_packages/commit/bbeec93c14e33d1294bc06584f07662f1909cc80

As you can see, my naive approach of using consecutive MyRouter.go() statements is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final GlobalKey<TabAState> tabAKey = GlobalKey<TabAState>();

void navigateToTabB(BuildContext context) {
  goRouter.resetTo(
    AppRoute.tabAStart.name, 
    navigatorKey: goRouter.navigatorKey,
    builder: (BuildContext context, StatefulRouter router, int tabIndex) {
      switch (tabIndex) {
        case 0:
          return TabA(key: tabAKey);
        case 1:
          return TabB();
        default:
          return Container();
      }
    },
  );


  context.goNamed(AppRoute.orders.name);
}
```

Comment: Hm, that would set the state of the current route back but I actually need to switch to a different route in Tab A before hopping over to Tab B. 
At the moment I have several routes in Tab A (start form -> middle form -> end form -> confirmation) and need to reset that while moving to Tab B.

Comment: ok i edit answer to use goRouter.resetTo does that work?

Comment: goRouter.resetTo does not seem to be a function of go_router. Not sure I'm getting your example.

Comment: good point. what about   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil and then goto B?

Comment: I've tried  'context.pushReplacementNamed(startTabA); context.goNamed(TabB)' and a few similar variations. Each time I see in my log that the route in Tab A has changed but when I later return the previous outdated endTabA route is restored.
I probably have to build a demo to fully show the issue.

Comment: [GoRouter] pushReplacement /startEdit
[GoRouter] getting location for name: "orders"
[GoRouter] going to /orders
[GoRouter] restoring /remainderEdit. <<<----- this should have been removed

Comment: what's the github url with demo source?

Comment: I've added a link to my example (a small modification of go_router's stateful_shell_route example) to the initial problem statement now.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a bug.

A workaround is to have a small delay before the second `.go`:

```dart
GoRouter.of(context). go('/a');
Future.delayed(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
  () => GoRouter.of(context).go('/c'),
);
```